# jdbc combine 2 sql update statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there a way to combine statements 1 and 2 into 1 query? Thanks.

```
String statement1 = "UPDATE thing SET status = ? WHERE id = ?";
String statement2 = "UPDATE thing SET error_message = ? WHERE id = ?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement1);
preparedStatement.setInt(1,status);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, id);
connection.prepareStatement(statement2);
preparedStatement.setInt(1,error_message);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, id);
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are trying to set 2 columns of same table for an ID. You can change the query like

```
"UPDATE thing SET status = ? ,error_message = ? WHERE id = ?"
```

Further more, if the 2 update statements are updating different tables, you can execute both in same transaction.  In this way, you can be sure that the **commit** will take place if **both** the statement successfully updates the table. [Check the example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
    String statement1 = "UPDATE thing SET status = ? ,error_message = ? WHERE id = ?";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement1);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1,status);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2,error_message);
    preparedStatement.setInt(3, id);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```